# Resources incorrectly interpreted upon loading default site

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, iis, mime

I am doing a MVC ASP.NET Application in a class, and in this class the program, which runs on Visual Studio Premium 2013, runs smoothly, and looks like this:

[image]

So now it's time to publish, and I've done all the professor asked. I published through IIS, the default site looking like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CTS2463</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>CTS2463 CLASS</p>
    <br />
    <p>Projects:</p>
    <br />
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http:/MvcMusicStore/">MvcMusicStore</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br />
  </body>
</html>
```

So the project `MvcMusicStore` is under `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` . It loads correctly, and I can register myself, "check out" an order and all. Yet, it looks like this:

[image]

As you see, no resources load. I clicked on one of the broken images and under Chrome's javascript debugger I get this:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml: "http://localhost/MvcMusicStore/Content/site.css". localhost/:8
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml: "http://localhost/MvcMusicStore/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js". localhost/:10
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml: "http://localhost/MvcMusicStore/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js". localhost/:117
```

So from what I understand, every resource (css, images, js) is being converted to xml. Why would this be happening? Please let me know if you have a solution for this, and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try using relative paths on Visual Studio. For styles, try using `Styles.Render(~/Styles/stle.css)` and for JS files `Scripts.Render(~/Scripts/script.js)`

Comment: I'm going to try and change this, but it wouldn't explain why it works for everyone else in class. Although everybody is running the program through a Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper V image, and I do this straight on my pc, Windows 8.1

Comment: Turns out the `_Layout.cshtml` file which contains the code you showed me already renders these resources from relative directories: `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` , `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")`

Comment: when I open one of the images by itself, `http://localhost/MvcMusicStore/Images/placeholder.png` , I get a page that displays this: `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`

Comment: you know what I did? I went to IIS, removed the application of my project, converted it again, and now it works 99% ... the only thing that doesn't seem to load is a file named `logo.svg` although I do have a `logo.png` on my images folder